# Sharing a video in a video conference call

Tags: video, sharing, video-conferencing, meetings

I have an interesting question. My company and a client will be having a meeting over Skype for business. I have prepared some videos that I would like to show at the meeting. I would like to stream these videos to the clients so that we can watch the videos at the same time. I would also like to "control" what everyone is seeing in terms of the video. For example, if I need to pause the video to explain a certain part to everyone.

I am aware that skype for business can kinda let you do this if you embed the video in a powerpoint. The only issue is that the file size must be below 25 MB. The video that I am playing is about 6 min long at 1080p resolution. The file size is 1.4 GB.

Also, we did try share screen for a different presentation once before and it was bad. The video was super choppy and horribly to watch. So that is out of the options

So, I am unable to use the skype for business solution. I was wondering, what does everyone else do in a situation like this? Is there some other solution that I can take? Is there some online solution that would allow me to upload to video to and give everyone a link and I can present it to them this way? Or should is something like this not possible?

Ideally I would like to have a solution that is web based so that I don't have to worry about the OS on either sides. But, if there are no solutions for web based, then we would be using Windows OS. Open source/free would also be ideal but I think that we would be willing to pay max $100 for a service

Comment: First, be aware that this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc. Second, I don't know what kind of network connection you and your participants have – are you aware that this video alone would require a bandwidth of ~4Mbyte/s (or > 30 MBit/s), and stable at that rate? Your describing the performance as "choppy" suggests the clients aren't up to that.

Comment: I did ask this question on the workplace SE and they are going to close it because they feel that it belongs to the software recommendation SE. So i posted it here

Comment: I am aware of that. It hasn't really crossed my mind because when we need to do video conference calls, the video on both ends comes through mostly clear

Comment: That video (conference software) isn't using the same resolution/quality/size as you want to share, obviously, as it even works fine on much lower network speeds. And just because someone "feels" (most often just arguing from the name of a site) something belongs here doesn't mean it's on-topic here :) To find out what's on- and what off-topic here, please take a look at [these questions](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) at our Meta site.

Comment: I am fine without any how to tutorials, I just need to know if there is anything out there that can allow me to stream video over the internet connection and allow simultaneously watching the video stream

Comment: In that case, and as we recommend software here, please [edit] your post accordingly and e.g. include what OS the software must run on as well as how much you're willing to spend on paid solutions.

Comment: Ok, I have edited it to include the recommended pieces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various websites that allow you to make a 'room' and watch youtube videos together with your 'room' participants. There is full control over the video in these rooms. This would require you to put these video files on youtube though, and that might not be ideal. It is, however, free and relatively easy to do.

Rabit and Gaze are examples of this.

I also found this, the free tier might be enough for you but you will have to test it yourself.
https://zoom.us/pricing

I assume there will be a lot of other conference tools around that have video playback as one of their features, but often I find that they try to shuffle that in under the 'Screen share' functionality as well.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info! I will check it out!